# cannot create key nltk-py2.7 error when installing Python Natural Language Toolkit

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to install the natural language toolkit on my Windows 8 machine with a 32bit Python 2.7 install

I'm following instructions here: http://www.nltk.org/install.html

At step 3 I get the following error: cannot create key nltk-py2.7

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Error similar to "Cannot find python" to occurs before this error and the Kyle's answer is the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try running the installation package with administrator right (Right click > Run as administrator).

I encountered these (and a few other) 'Could not set key value' errors when installing nltk 3.0.0b2 (32bit) on a Win8 machine:

- Python 3.4 nltk-3.0.0b2
- "C:\Program Files(x86)\Python\34\Removenltk.exe" "C:\Program Files(x86)\Python\34\nltk-wininst.log"

The installing is attempting to write values to the registry and failing with insufficient rights.

Comment: should have been selected as the answer